# SmartEdit works when spartacus is up with yarn start --ssl but not without ssl

Tags: javascript, angular

I have followed the steps for smartedit
https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/smartEdit-setup-instructions-for-spartacus/
and it works fine when Spartacus server starts with **yarn start --ssl**.
but When I am starting my server with **yarn start** storefront is not visible .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTQ0y.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `yarn start`, that's fine. But, you need to update the preview Url. Check step 5 in https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/smartEdit-setup-instructions-for-spartacus/. The preview url must match your web site.

Comment: I have followed the all the steps
 but still i cant load  smart edit page

Comment: You can open the preview url in browser to see whether it works. SmartEdit opens the preview url in iframe. So, the preview url must match your website url.